# codeigniter not working after installing zend Framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework, ubuntu-14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. 
i have done a project using codeigniter and that was working fine. 
but now i thought of learning zend framework and installed zend framework 1.12.3 on my machine using this tutorial [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-zend-framework-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps).

When i tried to access the new project i have created
    http://localhost/ZendApp
i get this error

```
        An error occurred
        Page not found
        Exception information:

        Message: Invalid controller specified (ZendApp)
        Stack trace:

        #0 /home/ZendFramework-1.12.3/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
        #1 /home/ZendFramework-1.12.3/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
        #2 /home/ZendFramework-1.12.3/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
        #3 /var/www/html/ZendApp/public/index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
        #4 {main}  

        Request Parameters:

        array (
          'controller' => 'ZendApp',
          'action' => 'index',
          'module' => 'default',
        )
```

And When i try to access my old project, i have done using codeigniter also i get the same error.

```
        An error occurred
        Page not found
        Exception information:

        Message: Invalid controller specified (lankahomes)
        Stack trace:

        #0 /home/ZendFramework-1.12.3/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
        #1 /home/ZendFramework-1.12.3/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
        #2 /home/ZendFramework-1.12.3/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
        #3 /var/www/html/ZendApp/public/index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
        #4 {main}  

        Request Parameters:

        array (
          'controller' => 'lankahomes',
          'action' => 'index',
          'module' => 'default',
        )
```

can someone help me to fix this problem. Tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's about your apache configuration ( i assume you use apache cause it's in digital ocean documentation )

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/ZendApp/public
```

with this configuration, your localhost domain is only working for your zend project. Change it's ServerName to another domain and add it to your /etc/hosts file like

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName zendproject.dev
      DocumentRoot /var/www/ZendApp/public
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 zendproject.dev
```

And restart your apache server. Then you can use zendproject.dev domain for your zend app and localhost for your default localhost directory. ( and i assume you have another apache vhosts conf file for localhost )